# how to set text an integer and get int without getting error

Tags: java, android

I tried to get the intent from integer. The String get intent works fine and displays well but when i put the integer i get a force close error.

```
package kfc.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class productdetail extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.productdetail);
        //stuff to get intent
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

        String productName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
        int productCalories = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("calories",0);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        String name = extras.getString("name");

        if (name != null) {
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.servingsize);
            text1.setText(productName);

        }
        //int calories = extras.getInt("calories");

            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calories);
            text1.setText(productCalories);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calories);
text1.setText(""+productCalories);
```

Or

```
text1.setText(String.valueOf(productCalories));
```

Comment: This is why Java is ridiculous sometimes...

Answer (score 8):

The method setText(int) looks for a string-resource with that specific int-id. What you want to do is call the setText(String) method which takes the supplied string instead.

You can convert your int to a String in a number of ways, but I prefer this one:

```
        TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calories);
        text1.setText(String.valueOf(productCalories));
```

EDIT: seems like someone already answered.