# Fault in Intent, app shuts down automatically

Tags: android, android-intent

Recently I entered the world of app development. I get stuck with the first intent unfortunately. I try to send the information from the numberpicker (in the main activity) to the page where the user can define the names of the players (addPlayersActivity). When simulating the app, it shuts down after clicking the button on the Main Activity. When deleting the code on the receiving side of the intent, the addPlayersActivity opens without any problems. The aim is to put the intent, the number of players, into an integer. To test this I created a TextField in receiving Activity that should show the value of the integer.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get the widgets reference from XML layout
    final TextView numberofplayers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectNumberPlayers);
    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);

    //Populate NumberPicker values from minimum and maximum value range
    //Set the minimum value of NumberPicker
    np.setMinValue(2);
    //Specify the maximum value/number of NumberPicker
    np.setMaxValue(8);

    //Gets whether the selector wheel wraps when reaching the min/max value.
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

    //Set a value change listener for NumberPicker
    np.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){
            //Display the newly selected number from picker
            numberofplayers.setText("# of Players: " + newVal);
        }
    });

}

public void onClick(View view){
    Intent getPlayerNamesIntent = new Intent(this, AddPlayersActivity.class);

    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.np);
    Integer numberOfPlayers = np.getValue();
    getPlayerNamesIntent.putExtra("NUM_PLAYERS", numberOfPlayers);

    startActivity(getPlayerNamesIntent);
}
}
```

The code at the addPlayersActivity

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class AddPlayersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_players);

    int numberOfPlayers = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NUM_PLAYERS");

    TextView chosenPlayers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chosenPlayers);
    chosenPlayers.setText(numberOfPlayers);

}

public void onClick(View view){
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ChallengesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
}
```

I would like to apologize in advance if this question is to vague, I just started out and I will improve myself over time.

Ivo

**EDIT**
Found what was wrong: an integer value cannot be the input for the setText().
[how to set text an integer and get int without getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327235/how-to-set-text-an-integer-and-get-int-without-getting-error)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to try it right away!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two `NumberPicker`s. So all the set up you do in oncreate is overridden by your new instance of `NumberPicker`.

```
public void onClick(View view){
    Intent getPlayerNamesIntent = new Intent(this, AddPlayersActivity.class);

    // NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.np);
    // Integer numberOfPlayers = np.getValue();
    int numberOfPlayers = np.getValue();
    getPlayerNamesIntent.putExtra("NUM_PLAYERS", numberOfPlayers);

    startActivity(getPlayerNamesIntent);
}
```

You also do not need to make your textview final.

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

**edit**
The variable needs to be accessible to all methods, so declared outside of the `oncreate`. Then initialised in `oncreate`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    NumberPicker np;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);
```

*Sorry my bad. I should've included this.*

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what i did wrong with the two Number Pickers. I tried your solution, np turns red and gives the error: cannot resolve symbol 'np'. I think this has something to do with the variable scope?

Comment: Thank you very much again. I learned from you how to make a variable accessible to all methods. And how to initialize the variable. I start to think that something else is wrong. I will rebuild the app new and inform you afterwards.